# twitter bootstrap dropdown menu not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a project I'm working on and for some reason, I can't get the dropdowns to work on my menu. I've included the proper files which leads me to believe it's a problem in my code.

Here's my page in action: https://git.jobud9.com/ (try the dropdown on the right side of the menu. Also don't mind the prompt your browser will issue because my certificate approval's still pending.)

And here's the code powering it:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Account
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>hi</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html code is correct. Maybe you forgot to attach a script? Look this [dropdown js](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns)

Comment: That fixed it. I thought it was an optional thing when I last read it. Thank you!

Comment: we have to jquery too, i didn't know tht.