# Bootstrap dropdown menu does not show list of links when clicked

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this is a common issue many have struggled with (I have listed similar questions below). I cannot get a dropdown menu to show its contents when clicked. I am attempting to use bootstrap.

```
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
                ...     

          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                 Courses <b class="caret"></b></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="pages/office.html">Office Hours</a></li>
                      </ul>
          </li>
                ...      
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

There are plenty of similar questions on stackoverflow, but none of the marked answers works for me.

I have tried (in many combinations):

- following the bootstrap components page: [bootstrap components](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns)
- ensuring js files are imported in correct order (jquery.js and then bootstrap.js)
- removing duplicate (remove bootstrap-dropdown.js as I already had bootstrap.js)
- updating versions

It is entirely possible (probable) that I'm missing something obvious, but I cannot for the life of me figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Links I've tried:
   [StackOverflow1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529574/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-not-working), [stackOverflow2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16867148/bootstrap-dropdown-menu-not-working), [stackOverflow3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527984/drop-down-menu-in-bootstrap-us-not-working), [stackOverflow4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592158/twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-not-working-in-any-browser), [stackOverflow5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115781/twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-menu-not-working), [stackoverflow6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766486/why-doesnt-this-bootstrap-dropdown-example-work)

Comment: Probably something else on the page interfering, can you post a live link? It works just fine when isolated: http://jsfiddle.net/bYDbL/

Comment: Wow... how embarrassing! Thanks for the second set of eyes!

Answer (score 0):

I was overlooking the obvious, I was missing the actual jquery file as Stano was kind enough to point out. Once I downloaded it, it worked fine.